# Why does uniq drop korean string?

Tags: sort, csv, locale, uniq

I have a CSV file containing 220k names that I want to batch import into a graph database. The batch importer imposes the restriction that each node must occur only once so I want to remove duplicates using `sort` and `uniq` like this:

```
sort all-authors.csv | uniq > unique-authors.csv
```

Upon investigating missing nodes I observed this odd behavior:

```
$ grep 이선동 unique-authors.csv
$ grep 이선동 all-authors.csv 
"이선동"
$
```

The name is passed on by `sort` but then lost by `uniq`:

```
$ sort all-authors.csv | grep 이선동
"이선동"
$ sort all-authors.csv | uniq | grep 이선동
$
```

It works with other non-English names, e.g.:

```
$ grep '잔쎈 우베' *csv
all-authors.csv:"잔쎈 우베"
unique-authors.csv:"잔쎈 우베"
$
```

What is happening here?

**edit: added output of locale**

```
 $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$
```

**edit: added output of attempt with single-line file and sort -u**

answering pLumo's comment regarding a file only containing the affected string:

```
$ grep 이선동 all-authors.csv > single-author.csv
$ sort single-author.csv | uniq
"이선동"
$
```

answering rush's comment regarding `sort -u`:

```
$ sort -u all-authors.csv | grep 이선동
```

I do not have any aliases set for uniq, I verified using `alias | grep uniq`, which returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982531/behaviour-of-gnu-sort-command-with-non-letter-ascii-characters-such-as-dot-or

This did the trick for me:

Without `LC_COLLATE=C`

```
sort test | uniq
이선동
```

With `LC_COLLATE=C`

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort test | LC_COLLATE=C uniq
동선이
동이선
선동이
선이동
이동선
이선동
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, `LC_COLLATE=C sort all-authors.csv | LC_COLLATE=C uniq | LC_COLLATE=C grep 이선동` returns nothing.

Comment: Strange, works for me, even with the grep:
`LC_COLLATE=C sort test | LC_COLLATE=C uniq | grep 이선동` returns: 이선동